# How can I extract a type from a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a class:

```
class Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   gender: string;

   constructor(params: any){
     this.name = params.name;
     this.age = params.age;
     this.gender = params.gender;
   }
}
```

How can I get a type from the class `Person` which is equivalent to:

```
 type PersonType = {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   gender: string;
 }
```

so I can use this to for the constructor params type. I don't want to duplicate the code to write the type definition like above code. I am looking for a way to get the type from the class definition.

I don't want to duplicate below code:

```
   name: string;
   age: number;
   gender: string;
```

Comment: that's not going to happen, you will need to type it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the class as type

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtNYAtvAFzQQAuiAlmgOYDcu0Ydp+AroQEZJN5s0AEyRlKNek2bB04jsAopEACgAOYREQhkEydAEoszPBQAW1CADoCxaAF5o6zYSs34-PNDMXLrePccNLV82DxNzK0ERRACnYKi+bGMvCMsEmIc4lzT4YSQAJgZoAHpi6CREJWYAX2xa7Bk0Si94SgBGALR4AHc4JFQ0ZUwWNjI2gBpodLIAcjaZybdZ+ehq-SZG5opWinzOnr69QeG-Mcnp6DmZ1fWSsoqqhvAoQ4G9nDwl8ipaOgCAIhEADMwBwQBR-h5TpweEgAgAGDwXcS-AHA0HgyFJPCbKjyRQqLLaV7ofKGD6eADy3AAVvAFL4oNQ6INvBBJkT1jU6klcS1KABmfa9XRvIYjdgTKa5aLLBb4IjsK43DayCj8igAFmFJLQ+XF0KlF2VayKpXKiEqiCAA)

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;

  constructor(params: Person) {
    this.name = params.name;
    this.age = params.age;
    this.gender = params.gender;

    this.gender = params.gender2; // error
  }
}

const test1 = new Person({ age: 1, gender: '1', name: '1' });
const test2 = new Person({ age: 1, gender: '1' }); // error
```

Or you can use Object.assign to initialize all fields at once, but then you need to specify a default value for all fields

```
class Person {
  name: string = "default";
  age: number = 0;
  gender: string = "default";

  constructor(params: Person) {
    Object.assign(this, params);
  }
}

const test3 = new Person({ age: 1, gender: '1', name: '1' });
const test4 = new Person({ age: 1, gender: '1' }); // error
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, I got you right.

but maybe you want this?

```
export class Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   gender: string;

   constructor(params: Person){
     this.name = params.name;
     this.age = params.age;
     this.gender = params.gender;
   }

  someMethod?: () => void = () => {};
}
```

**Usage Example**

```
const person: Person = new Person(...);
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use the type `any` in the constructor

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Ah! I see. I have an idea but I am not sure this is a correct way.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao the solution will work when you will have only the properties. But when you will have the methods too, in that case, this solution will not work, or you need to mark the methods as optional. I will update my answer with the working example

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes as a Type, e.g.

```
class A { name: string; };
let foo: A = { name: "John" };
```

However after seeing your comments, I'm wondering why you just don't type the constructor params?

```
export class Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   gender: string;

   constructor(name: string, age: number, gender: string){
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
     this.gender = gender;
   }
}
```

Where is a problem with this one?

Comment: The problem is the in my real case, there are more than 60 parameters in the constructor. I'd like to use one object parameter include all fields

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao then I'd suggest you use something like `constructor(params: Person)`, which you can call like `new Person({ name: "bla", age: 40, gender: "male" })`